# Getting the nth from last of the linked list

Tags: c, struct, reverse, singly-linked-list, function-definition

What I'm doing is that first I reversed the linked list and then actually I'm trying to get the nth value of a node. The problem is that the function isn't doing anything after it reverses the linked list and doesn't give an error for some reason.

Here's my code:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<assert.h>

// 1. Create a linked list first
struct Node {
  int data;
  struct Node* next;
};

// 2. Create traversal function for linked list
void linkedListTraversal(struct Node* ptr) {
  while (ptr != NULL) {
    printf("%d\n", ptr->data);
    ptr = ptr->next;
  }
}

// 3. Write a function to get the node value from the tail of the linked list
int getNode(struct Node* head, int positionFromTail) {
  int value;
  struct Node* prevNode = NULL;
  struct Node* currNode = head;
  struct Node* nextNode;

  while (currNode != NULL) {
    nextNode = currNode->next;
    currNode->next = prevNode;
    prevNode = currNode;
    currNode = nextNode;
  }
  head = prevNode;

  struct Node* ptr = head;
  int count = 0;

  while (ptr != NULL) {
    if (count == positionFromTail) {
      return (ptr->data);
      count = count + 1;
      ptr = ptr->next;
    }

  }
  assert(0);
}

int main() {
  struct Node* head;
  struct Node* second;
  struct Node* third;
  struct Node* fourth;

  head = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
  second = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
  third = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
  fourth = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

  head->data = 3;
  head->next = second;

  second->data = 2;
  second->next = third;

  third->data = 1;
  third->next = fourth;

  fourth->data = 0;
  fourth->next = NULL;

  linkedListTraversal(head);

  printf("The value of the node is %d", getNode(head, 2));
}
```

Here's my output and any help will be appreciated.

```
3
2
1
0
```

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do. I would do it as follows: 1) Traverse the list to count the number of nodes. 2) Convert position from tail into position from head. 3) Traverse the list to find the desired node.

Comment: Side note: you forgot `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: Having a function named `getNode` that reverses the list (and does not provide any mechanism for returning the new head to the caller, resulting in the caller having only a pointer to the last node in the list!) seems like a design fail.  Perhaps rename the function to `get_node_and_destroy_list`

Answer (score 2):

You can have an infinite loop because the pointer `ptr` is changed only when the condition of the if statement within the loop evaluates to true

```
while (ptr!=NULL)
{
 if (count == positionFromTail)
 {
  return (ptr->data);
  count = count + 1;
  ptr = ptr->next;
 }


}
```

Rewrite the for loop at least for example like

```
while ( ptr != NULL && positionFromTail-- )
{
    ptr = ptr->next;
}

if ( ptr != NULL )
{
    return ptr->data;
}
else
{
    // return some value
    return  -1;
}
```

Also the parameter `positionFromTail` shall have an unsigned integer type. Otherwise you need to check in the beginning of the function whether it has a negative value.

Pay attention to that after exiting the function your list will be broken. The pointer head in main will not be changed after calling the function but the value of the data member next of the node pointed to by the pointer and of other nodes will be changed. So in general your approach is incorrect.

There is no need to reverse the list to find an element at the given position counted from the end of the list.

For starters I would declare the function the following way

```
int getNode( const struct Node *head, int pos, int *data );
```

That is the function returns either 1 if there exists a node with the specified position or 0 otherwise. If there is a node with the specified position then the stored value is written in the dereferenced parameter `data`.

If the value of the parameter `pos` is not negative then counting of nodes starts from the head otherwise from the end of the list.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Node 
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};

void clear( struct Node **head )
{
    while (*head)
    {
        struct Node *current = *head;
        *head = ( *head )->next;
        free( current );
    }
}

size_t create( struct Node **head, const int a[], size_t n )
{
    clear( head );

    size_t i = 0;

    while (n-- && ( *head = malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) ) ) != NULL )
    {
        ( *head )->data = *a++;
        ( *head )->next = NULL;
        ++i;
        head = &( *head )->next;
    }

    return i;
}

FILE * display( const struct Node *head, FILE *fp )
{
    for (; head != NULL; head = head->next)
    {
        fprintf( fp, "%d -> ", head->data );
    }

    fputs( "null", fp );

    return fp;
}    

int getNode( const struct Node *head, int pos, int *data )
{
    int success = 0;

    if (!( pos < 0 ))
    {
        while (head != NULL && pos--)
        {
            head = head->next;
        }

        if (( success = head != NULL )) *data = head->data;
    }
    else
    {
        const struct Node *current = head;

        for ( ;current != NULL && pos; ++pos )
        {
            current = current->next;
        }

        while (current != NULL )
        {
            head = head->next;
            current = current->next;
        }

        if (( success = pos == 0 )) *data = head->data;
    }

    return success;
}

int main( void )
{
    struct Node *head = NULL;
    const int a[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    create( &head, a, sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ) );

    fputc( '\n', display(head, stdout ) );

    for (int i = 0, data; getNode( head, i, &data ); i++)
    {
        printf( "%d: %d; ", i, data );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    for (int i = -1, data; getNode( head, i, &data ); i--)
    {
        printf( "%d: %d; ", i, data );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    clear( &head );
}
```

The program output is

```
0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null

0: 0; 1: 1; 2: 2; 3: 3; 4: 4; 5: 5; 6: 6; 7: 7; 8: 8; 9: 9;
-1: 9; -2: 8; -3: 7; -4: 6; -5: 5; -6: 4; -7: 3; -8: 2; -9: 1; -10: 0;
```